# RequireJs only loading JQuery when I configure the path option

Tags: jquery, requirejs

My application structure looks like:

```
 ...
 javascripts/
    - main.js
    lib/
        - jquery-1.9.0.min.js
        - require.js
```

I have an HTML page like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main='/assets/javascripts/main' src='/assets/javascripts/lib/require.js'></script>
```

My main.js looks like:

```
//main.js
require.config({
    paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.9.0.min' }});

require(['jquery'], function($) {
    return $(function() {
        return console.log('dom ready');
    });
});
```

This all works fine, and the HTML page says 'dom ready' in the console. The problem is when I remove the paths configuration and try to load jquery like this:

```
//Updated main.js
require(['lib/jquery-1.9.0.min'], function($) {
    return $(function() {
        return console.log('dom ready');
    });
});
```

where I have removed the path configuration and have tried to load jquery by specifying its path. This gives me "undefined is not a function" in reference to the $ variable. Strangely, I still see jquery-1.9.0.min coming over the network initiated by require.js. What is going on here? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a bug. jQuery exports itself as a named module. This means you must have it as a path configuration option.

```
// Expose jQuery as an AMD module, but only for AMD loaders that
// understand the issues with loading multiple versions of jQuery
// in a page that all might call define(). The loader will indicate
// they have special allowances for multiple jQuery versions by
// specifying define.amd.jQuery = true. Register as a named module,
// since jQuery can be concatenated with other files that may use define,
// but not use a proper concatenation script that understands anonymous
// AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust way to register.
// Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are derived from
// file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase file name.
// Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants to call
// noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
}
```

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports.js

If you do not then the library will still load (as you've seen) but it won't be returned correctly to you require/define callback

Answer (score 0):

Change to `define` instead of `require`.

```
define(['lib/jquery-1.9.0.min'], function($) {
    return $(function() {
        return console.log('dom ready');
    });
});
```

Comment: This results in the same behavior.