# requirejs callback parameter is undefined

Tags: arguments, requirejs, undefined

I'm just starting with require.js. Here's the simple code that I have in my main.js

```
    require.config({
        baseUrl: '/js',
    });

    require(['lib/jquery-min'], function(jq){
        console.log (jq);   // Always returns "undefined"
    });
```

In the require function above, the argument jq is always returned as empty. Can you help me identify the issue here?

Comment: Just to let you know, I confirmed that 'jquery-min.js' file gets added properly, but just the problem with the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  [RequireJs only loading JQuery when I configure the path option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765830/requirejs-only-loading-jquery-when-i-configure-the-path-option)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-min'
    }
});

require(['lib/jquery-min'], function(jq){
    console.log (jq);   // Works now!!!
});
```